# image source with dots in Javascript

Tags: javascript, src

It's not a question by itself, but more about if it's correct.
I tried to add a background image in Javascript with

```
 .style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/image00.jpg')"
```

but it didn't work.
So I remove one dot :

```
 .style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/image00.jpg')"
```

and it worked. I thought in CSS it was two dots to go backward? Why is it only one in Javascript?

My current folder look like that :

- Folder 1

  - index.html
  - images

    - image.jpg
  - scripts

    - scripts.js
  - styles

    - styles.css

it's a bit weird that two dots are not working in JS, but work in CSS (for me).

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS or JavaScript. It's just a filepath.

Comment: ok, but why is it different?

Comment: Different from what? It's a relative filepath, so it depends on the location of the HTML file with the inline style or the CSS file.

Comment: is this code in the html file or the js file? ---  `.style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/image00.jpg')"`

Comment: If you're referring to that path from your HTML file, then a single dot is correct as that's in the current directory. If you're referring to it from your styles.css file, then it needs to go up one, then into the images directory, hence the double dot notation.

Comment: My code is in JS file

Comment: Your Javascript is affecting the style in the HTML file though, so single dot is correct. It's referring from the HTML file, not the JS file.

Comment: @Nic727 see ManoDestra comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single dot notation is correct when referring from the HTML file. This applies whether the CSS is in the HTML file, or whether you have JS that is affecting the CSS in the HTML file.

The double dot notation would be required if the style were defined in your styles.css file, as that needs to go up one directory, before going down again into the images directory.

It's simply [file path notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect. It is **not** one dot in JS and two in CSS. It is to do with filepaths, and how to reference files.

If you use two dots such as `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/image00.jpg')"` it goes up one directory level and looks for the file there.

One dot, `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/image00.jpg')"` like this means that it will look for the file in the current directory.

Comment: The CSS solution would have been close: style="background-image url(./images/image00.jpg);"

Comment: I added more explanation.